# VTK - Delete boundary edges of PolyData

Tags: vtk

I have a `PolyData` and I want to remove its  boundary edges.

There is a `vtkFeatureEdges` filter, which shows you boundary edges, but the problem is that it returna a new `PolyData`, without any regard to the the polydata on which filter was run initially.

1. Is there any way to get IDs of boundary vertices/edges in original polydata?
2. Is there a way to delete those boundary edges? For example, I want to compute Gaussian curvature on the PolyData, but without taking boundary edges into account, so something like this: vtkFeatureEdges on Original PolyData -> Delete those boundary edges in Original PolyData -> Do vtkCurvatures on the filtered PolyData.

Comment: I took a look at the source code of vtkFeatureEdges and unless I am mistaken, no association between the input and output is being created :( First solution that comes to mind is to use vtkMergePoints to create an index map of matching points between the input and output (vtkFeatureEdges uses it for point location as well, so it should work without any numerical issues) and then traverse the edges of each the output's points and find matching edges in the input using the created map and remove them....sounds like a bit too much work though, hopefully somebody has a more elegant solution

Comment: You can use vtkPloyData().GetPoints() to get all boundary points.

Comment: Agreed, this seems like an obvious feature.